# About Con($\mathfrak{u}>\mathfrak{i}$)?

Tags: set-theory

I need some help looking for a paper.

It is mentioned in a joint paper of M. Goldstern and S. Shelah that Shelah has proved the consistency of $\mathfrak{i}<\mathfrak{u}$. I was looking for this consistency proof, but I couldn't find anything. Does anyone know where  I can find Shelah's proof of $Con(\mathfrak{i}<\mathfrak{u})$?

Thanks in advance.

(I apologize if this is not the right place to ask this question).

Comment: First hit on google: http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01277485#page-1